# Why am I getting garbage characters in my output for Test 1 and Test3 occasionally?

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers

I am having problems with my test cases writing garbage to my result variable. I am pretty new to C, so I am having trouble determining what is causing it.

```
//Author: Ryan Fehr
//Contributors:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int remover(char[], char[], char[]);

int remover(char source[], char substring[], char result[])
{
    char *current = source;
    // printf("%s n", current);
    char *currentSub = substring;
    //printf("%c n", *currentSub);
    int i = 0;

    while(*current != '\0')//Loops through the source string
    {
        //Uncommenting the line below will show you the comparisons being performed
        printf(" %c | %c \n", *current, *currentSub);

        if(*current == *currentSub || *currentSub == '\0')//True when a letter matches with a letter in the subStr or the complete subStr was found
        {

            if(*currentSub == '\0')
            {
                char pre[((current-(i) - source))];//Stores everything before the subString in pre(current-i) - source
                memcpy(pre, source, (current-i) - source);
                printf("Pre: %s\n",pre);
                //Counts how many chars are after the substring
                int n = 0;
                while(*current != '\0')
                {
                    n++;
                    current++;
                }
                char post[n];//Stores everything after the subString in post
                memcpy(post, current-n, n);
                printf("Post: %s\n",post);
                strcat(result, pre);
                strcat(result,post);
                printf("Substring removed: %s\n", result);//Prints the value after substring has been removed
                return 1;
            }
            i++;
            currentSub++;
        }
        else
        {
            i=0;
            currentSub = substring;
        }
        current++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    //TEST 1
    char s[] = "jump_on_down_to_getfart_and_up_to_get_down_";
    char sub[] = "fart";
    char r[100] = "";
    printf("Test 1:\n");
    printf("Source: %snSubstring: %s\n",s,sub);
    printf("%d\n\n", remover(s, sub, r));
    //EXPECTED OUTPUT: 1
    //TEST 2
    strcpy(s, "racecar");
    strcpy(sub, "x");
    strcpy(r, "");
    printf("Test 2:n");
    printf("Source: %snSubstring: %s\n",s,sub);
    printf("%d\n\n", remover(s, sub, r));
    //EXPECTED OUTPUT: 0
    //TEST 3
    strcpy(s, "jump on down to get and up to get down ");
    strcpy(sub, "up");
    strcpy(r, "");
    printf("Test 3:n");
    printf("Source: %snSubstring: %s\n",s,sub);
    printf("%d\n\n", remover(s, sub, r));
    //EXPECTED OUTPUT: 1
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the output for Test1, as you can see I am getting extra garbage printing and I think my math is correct for my substrings, so I am not sure what is causing this.

[I can't embed images so it is linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbwEd.png)

Comment: 1) `strcat(result, pre);` : `result` does not have enough spaces.

Comment: in Standard C it is not permitted to have function definitions inside other functions; it would be a good idea to move those definitions out of `main`

Answer (score 4):

Nested functions are not a part of standard C.  Only GCC (and maybe Clang emulating, or in compatibility mode with, GCC) support it.  Do not post nested functions on Stack Overflow (or Code Review) if you want to get away without scathing comments being passed on the unsuitability of nested functions.

Your problem is that your variable `r` in `main` is an array of size `1`, but you use it in the `remover()` function as if it was bigger.  You get undefined behaviour as a result.

At minimum, you should use:

```
char r[100];  // Or any other convenient size - for the test data 50 would do
```

There may be other problems; I've not compiled the code (I decline to compile C code with nested functions; it won't pass my default compilation options).

Answer (score 2):

Do not insert one function inside another function.

The posted code has the `remover()` function nested inside the `main()` function.

While some compilers will allow that as an 'extension', (`gcc` comes to mind ) you should never nest functions.

For ease of readability and understanding: 1)  consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do... while, switch, case, default) via a blank line